# Need a loop to repeat as many times as the user entered

Tags: java, for-loop

I need help with this assignment.  **Here is what i need the program to do:

> - Write a program that prompts a user for a number of iterations.
> - The program should then loop that many times.
> - Each loop the program should prompt the user for a number and add it to a running total.
> - Print the running total when you are done.

I cant get the program to loop as many times as the user enters.  I know this is a simple fix but i cant seem to figure it out.  Am i using the wrong statement for the loop?

```
Scanner guess = new Scanner(System.in);

int count =0;
int sum=0;
int num;

System.out.println("Enter a number");
num = guess.nextInt();

for(count =0; count <= num; count++)
{
    sum +=num;
    System.out.println("Your results are:"+sum);
}
```

Comment: You never ask for a number inside the loop, I would start by adding that.

Comment: Your loop will iterate from 0 to num (including num). Try to count how many times will it be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are starting at 0, then you'll want to change

```
for(count =0; count <= num; count++)
```

to

```
for(count =0; count < num; count++)
```

because it starts at 0, so that is the first iteration, and 1 is the second, etc.

Also, you need to keep asking the user every time. So you'll want to do something like this in the loop:

```
sum += guess.nextInt();
```

Lastly, you DON'T want to print the sum every time, just at the END. So AFTER the loop, print the sum.

You might have thought that having `sum += num` will ask the user for another number, but num is just the first number that the user entered (it won't change). You need to get the user's input every iteration.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.  Good, easy fix.

Comment: Yes i was going to!  You have to wait five minutes before accepting an answer, i did now.  Thank you very much for your help.   I have another program that i need help with that i will be posting shortly.

Comment: Maybe try it yourself first though? I mean you are in some sort of CS class, you should try to use the things you learned in class to solve the problem by yourself. (Stackoverflow is more like a last resort)

Comment: Yes i am going to take what i learned from your solution, and see if i can do something similar.  I do enjoy it when i get programs working on my own. I have a A in the class so far!   It is a programming and logic course for java.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `<=` where you should be using just `<` in you `for` statement, otherwise you will go around the loop one to many times; and you should prompt for the number to add inside the loop, and include the appropriate code to keep track of the running sum there.

Something like this:

```
Scanner guess = new Scanner(System.in);

int count =0;
int sum=0;
int num, N;

System.out.println("How many numbers will you enter?");
N = guess.nextInt();

for(count =0; count < N; count++)
{
    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    num = guess.nextInt();
    sum +=num;
}

    System.out.println("The sum of the numbers entered is:"+sum);
```

Comment: Yes i know that.  This really is not a solution to my question.

Comment: @Chris: if you know that, why do you have this bug in your code? And why do you ask how if you're using the wrong statement for the loop? Yes, you're using the wrong statement, and that's how you must fix it. You didn't ask anything else in your question.

Comment: For the edit, essentially the same as my answer (but you might not have seen mine as you were editing).

Comment: @jaybob - yes I was writing this without seeing your answer (ipad not great for fast editing...). Agree basically the same.

Comment: Yes i saw it before the expanded answer.  Similar to jaybob's solution.  It is nice to see more ways to a solution.  Thank you.